# How do I pass query parameters using angular.js

Tags: angularjs, neo4j

I am trying to pass parameters for a cypher query. I have stepped through the sequence to xhr.send() and am passing it this data:

{"query":"match (U:User {UserID: {UID}})-[:HAS_ROLES]->(R: Roles) return R.Roles as Roles, {IDX} as indx","params":"{UID : \"0012\" ,IDX : 0} "}

Wireshark shows the data being sent to Neo4j as this:

Object
   Member Key: "query"
      String value: 
   Member Key: "params"
      Object

Every POST I send has an empty params object, so clearly the way I am passing this data is not correct.  How do I populate the params object?

I am using the ANNE stack.

Michael D. Spence
Mockingbird Data Systems, Inc.

```
            function runAdhocQueryParams(query,myparams) {
                var call = $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: { query: query, params: myparams },
                    url: '/api/runAdhocQuery',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                });

                return $q.when(call);
            }

    query is
    match (U:User {UserID: {UID}})-[:HAS_ROLES]->(R: Roles) return R.Roles as Roles, {IDX} as indx

    myparams is (in JSON)

    {
      "UID": "0012",
      "IDX": 0
    }
```

Comment: We have no idea how you are currently doing it...show your code

Comment: var call = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                data: { query: query, params: jsonifyObjectForNeo4J(myparams) },
                // data: { params: myparams, query: query },
                // data: { query: query },
                // params: params,
                // data: qAndP,
                url: '/api/runAdhocQuery',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            });

            return $q.when(call);

Comment: please edit question with properly formatted code and not put code blobs in comments

Comment: there is a help button on the editor toolbar...and a code block button also

Comment: I am trying to add a comment.  I see no help button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39937993/edit

Comment: function runAdhocQueryParams(query,myparams) {
                    var call = $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: { query: query, params: myparams },
                        url: '/api/runAdhocQuery',
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                    });
        
                    return $q.when(call);
                } 

I put 8 space in front of each line, but I still don't get the proper formatting.

Comment: you aren't editing the question ... click edit link right underneath it or the link i just posted

Comment: Ah.  I see what you mean.  Added to the question.